# Spring Integration FileReadingMessageSource STOPS Picking Files

Tags: java, spring-integration

Weirdly, our Spring Integration (2.7.3) running as a `Job` kind on AWS EKS container, stops picking files. The files that weren't picked originally, gets picked if the container is restarted. Below are our configuration.

Is something wrong with the `FileReadingMessageSource` usage?

```
@Bean
public PollerSpec pollerSpec() {

    return Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(100)
                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory)
                .transactional(pseudoTransactionManager);
}

@Bean
public FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource(final File inboundDirectory) {

    var source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(inboundDirectory);
    source.setScanner(directoryScanner());

    return source;
}

@Bean
public DirectoryScanner directoryScanner() {

    FileListFilter<File> filter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>(
            Arrays.asList(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(), new LastModifiedFileListFilter()));

    var scanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
    scanner.setFilter(filter);

    return scanner;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow startFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource(null), p -> p.poller(pollerSpec()))
                        .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(ERROR_CHANNEL, appErrorChannel))
                        .log(DEBUG, message -> "File Picked: " + message.getHeaders().get(FILENAME))
                        .......
                        .......
}
```

Comment: Probably the poller thread is stuck someplace in user code; take a thread dump the next time it happens.

Comment: Followed your inputs on a different thread and implemented `MessageSourceMutator` and was able to verify poller running fine. Has it got anything to do with `.maxMessagesPerPoll(100)` as the container runs just on 500MB? It was also observed to work fine after changing to `.maxMessagesPerPoll(10)`